# SFML c++ How change Sprites per Primitives on Asteroid Game Code(Have Sprite Code Working)

Tags: c++, sfml, primitive

I have some code that when compiled, runs an Asteroid Game. I want to make some changes. In place of sprites for the ship, I would like to use trianges. For a bullet, I'd like to use a small rectangle, and finally, a polygon for the asteroids. The code uses an Entity Master Class with a list. Can somebody please elaborate on how to make these changes?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
using namespace sf;

const int W = 1200;
const int H = 800;

float DEGTORAD = 0.017453f;

class Animation
{
 public:
 float Frame, speed;
 Sprite sprite;
 std::vector<IntRect> frames;

 Animation(){}

 Animation (Texture &t, int x, int y, int w, int h, int count, float Speed)
 {
   Frame = 0;
   speed = Speed;

   for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    frames.push_back( IntRect(x+i*w, y, w, h)  );

   sprite.setTexture(t);
   sprite.setOrigin(w/2,h/2);
   sprite.setTextureRect(frames[0]);
 }


 void update()
 {
   Frame += speed;
   int n = frames.size();
   if (Frame >= n) Frame -= n;
   if (n>0) sprite.setTextureRect( frames[int(Frame)] );
 }

 bool isEnd()
 {
   return Frame+speed>=frames.size();
 }

};


class Entity
{
 public:
 float x,y,dx,dy,R,angle;
 bool life;
 std::string name;
 Animation anim;

 Entity()
 {
   life=1;
 }

 void settings(Animation &a,int X,int Y,float Angle=0,int radius=1)
 {
   anim = a;
   x=X; y=Y;
   angle = Angle;
   R = radius;
 }

 virtual void update(){};

 void draw(RenderWindow &app)
 {
   anim.sprite.setPosition(x,y);
   anim.sprite.setRotation(angle+90);
   app.draw(anim.sprite);

   CircleShape circle(R);
   circle.setFillColor(Color(255,0,0,170));
   circle.setPosition(x,y);
   circle.setOrigin(R,R);
   //app.draw(circle);
 }

 virtual ~Entity(){};
};


class asteroid: public Entity
{
 public:
 asteroid()
 {
   dx=rand()%8-4;
   dy=rand()%8-4;
   name="asteroid";
 }

 void update()
 {
   x+=dx;
   y+=dy;

   if (x>W) x=0;  if (x<0) x=W;
   if (y>H) y=0;  if (y<0) y=H;
 }

};


class bullet: public Entity
{
 public:
 bullet()
 {
   name="bullet";
 }

 void  update()
 {
   dx=cos(angle*DEGTORAD)*6;
   dy=sin(angle*DEGTORAD)*6;
   // angle+=rand()%7-3;  /*try this*/
   x+=dx;
   y+=dy;

   if (x>W || x<0 || y>H || y<0) life=0;
 }

};


class player: public Entity
{
 public:
 bool thrust;

 player()
 {
   name="player";
 }

 void update()
 {
   if (thrust)
    { dx+=cos(angle*DEGTORAD)*0.2;
      dy+=sin(angle*DEGTORAD)*0.2; }
   else
    { dx*=0.99;
      dy*=0.99; }

  int maxSpeed=15;
  float speed = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  if (speed>maxSpeed)
   { dx *= maxSpeed/speed;
     dy *= maxSpeed/speed; }

  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;

  if (x>W) x=0; if (x<0) x=W;
  if (y>H) y=0; if (y<0) y=H;
 }

};


bool isCollide(Entity *a,Entity *b)
{
return (b->x - a->x)*(b->x - a->x)+
       (b->y - a->y)*(b->y - a->y)<
       (a->R + b->R)*(a->R + b->R);
}


int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  RenderWindow app(VideoMode(W, H), "Asteroids!");
  app.setFramerateLimit(60);

  Texture t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7;
  t1.loadFromFile("images/spaceship.png");
  t2.loadFromFile("images/background.jpg");
  t3.loadFromFile("images/explosions/type_C.png");
  t4.loadFromFile("images/rock.png");
  t5.loadFromFile("images/fire_blue.png");
  t6.loadFromFile("images/rock_small.png");
  t7.loadFromFile("images/explosions/type_B.png");

  t1.setSmooth(true);
  t2.setSmooth(true);

  Sprite background(t2);

  Animation sExplosion(t3, 0,0,256,256, 48, 0.5);
  Animation sRock(t4, 0,0,64,64, 16, 0.2);
  Animation sRock_small(t6, 0,0,64,64, 16, 0.2);
  Animation sBullet(t5, 0,0,32,64, 16, 0.8);
  Animation sPlayer(t1, 40,0,40,40, 1, 0);
  Animation sPlayer_go(t1, 40,40,40,40, 1, 0);
  Animation sExplosion_ship(t7, 0,0,192,192, 64, 0.5);


  std::list<Entity*> entities;

  for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
  {
    asteroid *a = new asteroid();
    a->settings(sRock, rand()%W, rand()%H, rand()%360, 25);
    entities.push_back(a);
  }

  player *p = new player();
  p->settings(sPlayer,200,200,0,20);
  entities.push_back(p);

  /////main loop/////
  while (app.isOpen())
  {
      Event event;
      while (app.pollEvent(event))
      {
          if (event.type == Event::Closed)
              app.close();

          if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
           if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Space)
            {
              bullet *b = new bullet();
              b->settings(sBullet,p->x,p->y,p->angle,10);
              entities.push_back(b);
            }
      }

  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) p->angle+=3;
  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))  p->angle-=3;
  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) p->thrust=true;
  else p->thrust=false;


  for(auto a:entities)
   for(auto b:entities)
   {
    if (a->name=="asteroid" && b->name=="bullet")
     if ( isCollide(a,b) )
         {
          a->life=false;
          b->life=false;

          Entity *e = new Entity();
          e->settings(sExplosion,a->x,a->y);
          e->name="explosion";
          entities.push_back(e);


          for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
          {
           if (a->R==15) continue;
           Entity *e = new asteroid();
           e->settings(sRock_small,a->x,a->y,rand()%360,15);
           entities.push_back(e);
          }

         }

    if (a->name=="player" && b->name=="asteroid")
     if ( isCollide(a,b) )
         {
          b->life=false;

          Entity *e = new Entity();
          e->settings(sExplosion_ship,a->x,a->y);
          e->name="explosion";
          entities.push_back(e);

          p->settings(sPlayer,W/2,H/2,0,20);
          p->dx=0; p->dy=0;
         }
   }


  if (p->thrust)  p->anim = sPlayer_go;
  else   p->anim = sPlayer;


  for(auto e:entities)
   if (e->name=="explosion")
    if (e->anim.isEnd()) e->life=0;

  if (rand()%150==0)
   {
     asteroid *a = new asteroid();
     a->settings(sRock, 0,rand()%H, rand()%360, 25);
     entities.push_back(a);
   }

  for(auto i=entities.begin();i!=entities.end();)
  {
    Entity *e = *i;

    e->update();
    e->anim.update();

    if (e->life==false) {i=entities.erase(i); delete e;}
    else i++;
  }

 //////draw//////
 app.draw(background);
 for(auto i:entities) i->draw(app);
 app.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Warning: When you find sequentially numbered variables like `Texture t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7;` what you almost certainly want is an array. And in the cases where you don't want an array, you want descriptive names. They greatly assist in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

it is not really relevant question to be asked here,
but take a look at this part of code:

```
  Texture t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7;
  t1.loadFromFile("images/spaceship.png");
  t2.loadFromFile("images/background.jpg");
  t3.loadFromFile("images/explosions/type_C.png");
  t4.loadFromFile("images/rock.png");
  t5.loadFromFile("images/fire_blue.png");
  t6.loadFromFile("images/rock_small.png");
  t7.loadFromFile("images/explosions/type_B.png");
```

Comment: @JamesLerry you will find that using arithmetic to generate and draw the objects rather than using sprites will result in a radically different looking program. It is rare that you can make such a large ideological change to a program and get away with a small change.

Comment: I think the can be use same math values here like movement ship update ship bullet i just need a north for how use vertex for create a ship and use the math code here.Please if anybody know please help me